# How to fix '&' in XeLaTeX

Tags: math-mode, align, alignment

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts}

\begin{document}

$g^n\circ g^m=\underbrace{g \circ \dots \circ g}_\text{n times}\circ \underbrace{g \circ \dots 
\circ g}_\text{m times}=\underbrace{g \circ \dots \circ g}_\text{n+m times}&=\underbrace{g 
\circ \dots \circ g}_\text{m+n times} =\underbrace{g \circ \dots \circ g}_\text{m times}\circ 
\underbrace{g \circ \dots \circ g}_\text{n times}=\\&=g^m\circ g^n$
\end{document}
```

The `&` does not work in my code. I want it to make the equals that come after the `&` be one under the other. But the output I get is:
[image]

And I don't know if it has anything to do with it, But I noticed that the page did not start at the beginning of it, so maybe the two things come together.

Comment: The use of `$...$` is for unaligned, inline math.  You would, for starters, need to use a display math environment that supports alignment, such as `align`.

Comment: But it works the same, and it does not give me any errors, nor warnings

Comment: @ArielFishbein inside `align` you'll also have to use explicit line breaks with `\\ `.

Comment: I used them here, right before  the second '&='

Comment: Actually, how is it that you don't get any errors? When I run your code in XeTeX I definitely get errors, and it's definitely supposed to produce one.

Comment: @bonk I can't upload pictures as comments, so can't show you. But I don't lol

Comment: You do get errors from your posted code, check your log file, the `&` will give errors as they arenot in an alignment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must use an alignment environment: `&` doesn't work in inline math. Anyway, such a big object should be displayed.

I'd, first of all, define a local command in order to ease input and avoid clutter.

Here I propose three ways to typeset the thing (the names should make it clear what's my opinion about them).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\subsection*{Good}

\begin{equation*}
\newcommand{\gcirc}[1]{%
  {\underbrace{g\circ\dots\circ g}_{\text{$#1$ times}}}%
}
\begin{aligned}
g^n\circ g^m
  &= \gcirc{n} \circ \gcirc{m} \\
  &= \gcirc{n+m} = \gcirc{m+n} \\
  &= \gcirc{m} \circ \gcirc{n} = g^m\circ g^n
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

\subsection*{Bad}

\begin{equation*}
\newcommand{\gcirc}[1]{%
  {\underbrace{g\circ\dots\circ g}_{\text{$#1$ times}}}%
}
\begin{aligned}
g^n\circ g^m
  &= \gcirc{n} \circ \gcirc{m} = \gcirc{n+m} = \gcirc{m+n} \\
  &= \gcirc{m} \circ \gcirc{n} = g^m\circ g^n
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

\subsection*{Ugly}

\begin{equation*}
\newcommand{\gcirc}[1]{%
  {\underbrace{g\circ\dots\circ g}_{\text{$#1$ times}}}%
}
\begin{aligned}
g^n\circ g^m
  &= \gcirc{n} \circ \gcirc{m} = \gcirc{n+m} = \gcirc{m+n}
   = \gcirc{m} \circ \gcirc{n} \\
  &= g^m\circ g^n
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note the braces around the `\underbrace` command. It's not really so important here, but it could be in other situations. Also `_\text{...}` is wrong and should be `_{\text{...}}`.

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
g^n\circ g^m&=\underbrace{g \circ \dots \circ g}_\text{n times}\circ \underbrace{g \circ \dots 
\circ g}_\text{m times}=\underbrace{g \circ \dots \circ g}_\text{n+m times}=\underbrace{g 
\circ \dots \circ g}_\text{m+n times} =\underbrace{g \circ \dots \circ g}_\text{m times}\circ 
\underbrace{g \circ \dots \circ g}_\text{n times}=\\
&=g^m\circ g^n
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or perhaps you wanted

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
g^n\circ g^m=\underbrace{g \circ \dots \circ g}_\text{n times}\circ \underbrace{g \circ \dots 
\circ g}_\text{m times}=\underbrace{g \circ \dots \circ g}_\text{n+m times}&=\underbrace{g 
\circ \dots \circ g}_\text{m+n times} =\underbrace{g \circ \dots \circ g}_\text{m times}\circ 
\underbrace{g \circ \dots \circ g}_\text{n times}=\\
&=g^m\circ g^n
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It works. Can you explain to me breifly please what is the difference between \begin{align} and \begin{align*}? and also, why your code worked and mine didn't? I'm talking about your second code

Comment: you used `$` so no alignment at all (in fact the `&` would have generated an error so by default you would have no output at all) like most alignments `align` will put equation numbers (1), (2) at the right edge of the page, but `align*` does not number the equations, @ArielFishbein